Chrome on Android prefers apple touch icon over SVG favicon
I'm testing favicon in a web page in my local, non-HTTPS, vitejs development server.
This is the part related to favicon:
<link
  rel="icon"
  href="/favicon-32x32-light.png"
  sizes="32x32"
  media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)"
/>
<link
  rel="icon"
  href="/favicon-32x32-dark.png"
  sizes="32x32"
  media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"
/>
<link
  rel="apple-touch-icon"
  href="/apple-icon-180x180-light.png"
  sizes="180x180"
  media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)"
/>
<link
  rel="apple-touch-icon"
  href="/apple-icon-180x180-dark.png"
  sizes="180x180"
  media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"
/>
<link
  rel="icon"
  href="/favicon.svg"
  type="image/svg+xml"
  sizes="any"
/>

SVG has a viewBox like viewBox="0 0 160 160", not sure if this impacts browser selection algorithm. It includes a <style> tag to support both color schemes:
.inside {
  fill: green;
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .inside {
    fill: red;
  }
}

In Windows Chrome (and Firefox, Edge) only the SVG favicon is requested and then applied:

In Android Chrome (v129.0.xxx) both the SVG favicon and apple touch icon are requested and then the apple touch one is applied (the SVG has distinct colors so to be spotted):

My understanding is that Android Chrome supports SVG as favicon and its selection algorithm should pick the SVG one. So I guess there must be something wrong in my page setup. Here's MDN:

If there are multiple <link rel="icon">s, the browser uses their media, type, and sizes attributes to select the most appropriate icon. If several icons are equally appropriate, the last one is used. If the most appropriate icon is later found to be inappropriate, for example because it uses an unsupported format, the browser proceeds to the next-most appropriate, and so on.

A post on realfavicongenerator.net explains that Android Chrome relies on apple touch icon too, based on width/height calculation. But the SVG can be scaled as needed, so my understanding is it should take precedence.
Things I tried, with no luck:

changing order of <link> tags
removing sizes attribute either in apple touch icon, or SVG, or both
duplicating SVG <link> with distinct media attributes for dark/light scheme
authoring a scaled up SVG with a viewBox larger than 180x180, e.g. 200x200
exposing local site through HTTPS

The only way to make it pick SVG is to delete the two apple touch icon <link> tags. At that point, between the 32x32 PNG and SVG, Android Chrome picks SVG.
This is a codesandbox showing the issue, with a simpler setup too (no dark/light variants): https://s3cnww.csb.app/
Does anyone know how to make Android Chrome pick SVG? TA

Maybe try reporting the problem to Chrome's bugtracker

Did it, here it is. Still, it maybe that chrome is fine and it's just me having a wrong understanding. So, if anyone knows better...

You cannot choose which Favicon is preferred when the browser needs to choose among several. Each browser has its own implementation and as suggested by Robert Longson your only solution is to directly contact each browsers to check if it is the expected behavior.
For instance here are the rules for Safari browsers using apple-touch-icon: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW4.

hi, thanks for answering. Yes each browser has its rules. My understanding (which might be wrong) is that Android Chrome is not respecting the rules that it should. Current last comment in bugtracker speaks about "a bug", so maybe it should work differently. We'll see

Ok I see. SVG implementation is not yet perfect since it looks like it is "new" compared to others. Let's hope they will be able to say if it is a bug or not
